# Is this Leshen homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, racial-traits

The Leshen are a race of plant-like fey, born from places over flowing with druidic magic. It is said that when the elves came to the Material Plane from the Feywild, they planted a sacred grove for their wild god. Ages later, the grove still stands, but the elves are long gone from those lands, now enveloped by demonic power. A bastion of purity at the edge of the demonic wastes, the sacred trees birthed a race of vigilant protectors, clearing a portion of the corruption. In time the race spread, though its rarity remained. Leshen are iron-willed and zealous in their guard of nature, they often oppose more civilized races encroaching on wild lands. Leshen appear as Humanoid creatures, with bones of wood and skins of thorny, tough plant material. The race uses the general post *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* template.

- **Ability Scores:** Choose one of: (a) Choose any +2; choose any other +1 (b) Choose any +1; choose any other +1; choose any other +1
- **Creature Type:** Fey
- **Size:** Medium (5-6 feet tall)
- **Speed:** 30 ft.
- **Vigil.** You have advantage on any Wisdom (Survival) checks made to track fiends, undead or aberrations, as well as on any Intelligence checks to recall information about them.
- **Symbiosis.** You know the *Infestation* cantrip and can cast it without requiring any components.
  Starting at 3rd level, you can cast the *Ensnaring Strike* spell with this trait, without requiring a material component. Once you cast that spell with this trait, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest. You can also cast it using any spell slots you have of the appropriate level.
  Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells when you cast them with this trait (choose when you select this race).
- **Sylvan Talents.** You gain proficiency with one of the following skills of your choice: Animal Handling, Nature, Medicine, Stealth and Survival.

Comment: Why would they know more about fiends than about plants and animals?

Comment: Because they are destroyers of evil and unnatural and can sense it's stench with ease.

Answer (score 10):

### This is slightly weak

I'll use [detect balance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/200314/what-is-detect-balance) here. It works well if there are no strong synergies between abilities, and if the abilities are close to the standard racial ones, which is the case here. It recommends a total score of 25, and a range of 24-27.

**Ability Score Increase** is standard +12

**Speed, Size** are standard +0.

**Creature Type** non-humanoid +2

**Vigil** I'll treat this as Advantage on a Situational roll. There are quite a lot of undead, fiends and aberarrations, so knowing about them can be valuable and will come up occasionally. The tracking, probably less so. (If you think this is only a rare roll, it only would only be +1.)  +2

**Symbiosis** One cantrip is worth 2, a level one spell from 3rd is another 2. Neither of the two spells is known for being overpowered or useless (although *Infestation* is a weak damage cantrip), so the standard values should serve fine.  +4

**Sylvan Talents** Choice of a skill proficiency is worth +3

**Total: 22-23 points**

Even giving some features the benefit of doubt, this is below the recommended range, so it probably is a bit too weak. It could use one more thematic feature worth at least 2-3 points, for example a level 2 spell at 5th level, the ability to speak with small beasts, 13+Dex natural armor, mimicry, mask of the wild or similar.

Comment: I think te accumulation of different situations in which Vigil works makes it advantage on a situational roll not a rare one.

Comment: @AlexSash wouldn't that heavily depend on the setup of the adventure you're running?

Comment: Is the spell once daily  (long rest) still 2 points? Seems a bit much imho

Comment: @Hobbamok It is, see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin ah, my bad thanks for the link, I remembered a different (worse) table then

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the spell rating. Ensnaring strike is ok, but infestation is terrible, probably the worst damage cantrip in the game.

Comment: @SeriousBri I agree among the damage cantrips it is among the worst (low die, and the games worst damage type), but it still is a damage cantrip, so it is not entirely useless. I'd rate something like Friends or True Strike as really bad. So one average, one sup-par, one normal - not *that* bad. I can add a note the cantrip is on the weaker side.

Comment: @nitsua60, Sure, done.

Answer (score -3):

That seems balanced to me, nothing sticks out as being problematic. This seems like a solid basis for a control character, or a good druid stand-in with more flavor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: At first glance, my thought was that the race was quite underpowered and lacking in at least one, maybe two more features depending on how strong they are. That said, your answer claims it is balanced, but doesn't seem to do anything to support it. Your answer doesn't give me any reason to change my off-the-cuff opinion because your answer is also just an off-the-cuff opinion.

Comment: How is the race under powered? @ThomasMarkov

Comment: @AlexSash Like I said, I’ve only taken a cursory look at it, and I probably don’t have time today to do a proper analysis and write an appropriately thorough answer. But the answer above is no more supported than me just telling you I think it’s underpowered.