# Replacing one of multiple instances of innate damage resistance in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, house-rules, racial-traits, damage-resistance

Since damage resistance doesn't stack in D&D 5e, is there a consistent ruling or general consensus for replacing one damage resistance with another in the event that multiple instances of the same damage resistance would be held innately by a character?

The reason being that I want to make a shadar-kai character, and I want to use the baleful scion feat, but the double necrotic resistance would be a waste. Not regarding spells or other temporary effects, just static resistances. I imagine replacing one with something like poison or cold resistance would be thematic if allowed.

I know it's ultimately up to the DM, I'm just looking for community consensus before I bother making the character and finding a group.

Comment: I expect the close vote is because you asked for consensus, but this site does rules. If you change it to just focus on either rules, or possibly balance issues, then you may get a less negative reception. It wasn't my close vote by the way, and welcome to the site

Comment: Welcome. It often helps if you do not accept an answer on the same day, as there may be others who will provide you with an alternative answer you can choose from. As SeriousBri mentioned the answer you got is not "consensus" but one person's thinking.

Comment: Note: the [Baleful Scion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/baleful-scion) feat doesn't grant any kind of damage resistance. It's the Scion of the Outer Planes feat that grants resistance to a damage type (and choosing the Evil Outer Plane grants resistance to necrotic damage specifically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Its up to the DM, but you can look at Detect Balance

The *DMG* on p. 286 walks us through creating a new race using the Aasimar as an example, and contrasting it to the Tiefling. It has this to say about switching out resistances:

> Like tieflings, aasimar have darkvision. Instead of resistance to fire damage, we give them resistance to radiant damage to reflect their celestial nature. However, **radiant damage isn't as common as fire damage, so we give them resistance to necrotic damage as well**, making them good at facing undead.

This advises you to not switch common resistances against less common ones on a 1:1 basis. It matches the treatment in [Detect Balance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200314/75095), a tool to evaluate how balanced racial features are to each other power wise, by assigning a point value for them (which oversimplifies things). This is probably as good as anything to established consensus that you can get.

It groups resistances like this:

- **Rare Resistance** Radiant, Force, Psychic or Thunder (2 points)
- **Medium Resistance** Cold, Lightning, Necrotic, or Acid  (3 points)
- **Common Resistance** Fire or Poison (4 points)
- **Nonmagical Physical Resistance**    Slashing or Piercing.  (10 points), Bludgeoning (12 points)

If you replace necrotic,  you could replace it with at best another medium resistance like cold or acid, that matches the narrative background (depending on the campaign, of course). Because you would not normally get anything out of double resistance, this is already better than what you would get by the rules.  Poison or fire, which are more commonly encountered would be a further upgrade over that.

This is different from skills, where the rules tell you that if you get the same skill twice from your class or background, you can pick another one instead (p. 124, *PHB*).

---

Note, both radiant snd necrotic would be 5 points instead of 3, for the example given in the *DMG*, so both solutions by Detect Balance are off by a point. As long as it is that close, a generous DM might be fine to allow poison instead of necrotic.

Comment: I would think it would be better to trade it for a rare resist rather than another medium resist. By RAW you get nothing for duplicate resistances, so getting *anything* is putting you ahead of where you theoretically should be.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I think you are right (and I as DM would probably give a rare one at best. I changed the answer on that aspect.