# Is this "Parrotfolk" Homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, races

As per title, searching for second opinion on the race's balance.

### Racial fluff: [here](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Parrotfolk_(5e_Race))

### Racial traits

**Ability Score Increase.** Your Intelligence score increases by 2 and your Dexterity score increases by 1.

**Age.** Parrotfolk mature at age 16, and can live up to 80 years.

**Alignment.** They are a mostly good race, and almost always chaotic.

**Size.** Parrotfolk vary widely in height and build, from barely 5 feet to well over 6 feet tall. Your size is Medium.

**Speed.** Your base walking speed is 30 feet, you also have a climbing speed equal to your walking speed.

**Glide.** When you fall at least 10 feet above the ground, you can use your reaction to extend your wings to glide horizontally a number of feet equal to your walking speed, and you take 0 damage from the fall. You determine the direction of the glide.

**Tool Manipulators.** You gain proficiency in one set of tools of your choice.

**Linguists.** When you listen to conversations of two beings in an unfamiliar language for at least eight hours, you learn enough of words and grammar to strike short, simple conversations with creatures also talking in this language. If you would spend an additional eight hours speaking in this language with someone who knows it, you learn it fully.

**Visage of Feathers.** You are naturally proficient in looking good and presenting yourself. You have advantage on Charisma (Performance) rolls to make yourself look appealing.

**Companion.** You can cast Find Familiar spell with this trait without using a spell slot. You can summon only a parrot. It has the statistics of a hawk with Intelligence score of 8.

**Languages.** You can speak, read, and write Parrotfolk, Common, Auran and two other languages of your choice.

Comment: "vary widely" in height ... i.e. between 5-6 feet, does not seem very varied to me :) (just an observation). +1 for your homebrew and that it does seem balanced. Nobody the Hobgoblin has put in all the work so I won't repeat :D

Comment: @Senmurv my brother in Christ, this is word for word human size description from PHB :)

Comment: Wait, what?! ...hmm I guess not all in the PHB is logical. ;) Fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is balanced

Using Detect Balance to score this (see here for [qualifiers on that approach](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200314/75095)), where between 24 and 27 points is considered balanced, PH races average 25 points.

- Bog standard stuff (**+2/+1 ASI, Age, Alignment, size**) - **12 points**.
- This lacks a creature type. I'll assume humanoid (Aaracokra, who have full flight also have Humanoid, so wings are no issue). Still, you should call it out.
- **Climb Speed**. **2 points**.
- **Glide**: This could be written more clearly; while terseness is elegant, it may be better to spell things our explicitly to avoid misunderstandings. For example, what happens if you drop 200 feet and you glide 30 feet horizontally, do you still take 0 damage? Do you need to glide to avoid damage, or are they indpendent? What happens if you don't have enough space to glide? I'll treat this like always on Feather fall, although it has some added benefits for crossing chasms and such if you start out higher. **3 points**.
- **Tool Manipulators**. Choice of Tool proficiency. **1 point**.
- **Languages and Linguist**. Common plus 3 languages would be 1 point. This has four extra languages. Plus linguistics allows you to pick up even more languages, that you than can use fully, on the cheap, without limit. How useful this is will depend on the campaign and time you have, but I think you can pick up at least 3 languages with this and if not more this is **2 points**.
- **Visage of Feathers**. I'll use Advantage on a rare roll - Performance in practice [is not used that often](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/pwnwpu/what_skills_are_called_for_most_a_critical_role/), and as written it only works to make yourself look appealing, not for other objective. Might be more useful if playing a bard. **1 point**.
- **Companion**. Not using a spell slot would still need the components, gp cost, casting time etc. I assume that is the intent, so there is some kind of limitation how often you can do that. *Find familiar* already is a ritual that you can cast as often as you want without a slot if you have ritual casting, and this version is much more limited due to not being able to choose different forms. A single time first level spell use, usable at level 1 is already 4 points. Familars also are strong and can change how the game plays, so this should be more valuable. I'd value this at **5 points**.

There are not special synergies that I can see that would break the additive nature of the evaluation, so we are looking at overall 12 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 5 = **26 points**. This is middle of the range, so even if I'm off by 1 or 2 points on something, still should be fine.

Comment: I approve your answer (I was about to fill the spreadsheet as well). The Linguists trait could be abused though, especially the last part for learning a language fully.

Comment: @Yotus language is fluffy enough that abuse isn't really abusive. The DM is only going to let you have an 8 hour conversation if they want you to learn the language anyway.